# Recurrent relation for a series: does this yields to divergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a series $\Sigma a_k X^k$ that satisfies: $$\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_k} = -\frac{l(l+1)-k(k+1)}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$

This yields to $$\frac{a_{k+2}}{a_k} {\sim}_{+\infty} 
1$$

Assuming that $l$ never satisfies $$l(l+1) -k(k+1)=0$$

Assuming this, can I conclude that $\Sigma a_k X^k$ diverges
?

PS: The only rule I know is the D'Alembert ratio test, according to which we cannot conclude

EDIT:

Next, in the [Morgan hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), is the Raabe's test, so I have tried it:

$$k(\frac{a_k}{a_{k+2}} -1) = k\frac{(k+1)(k+2)-k(k+1)+l(l+1)}{k(k+1)-l(l+1)}
$$
$$ =\frac{2k^2+2k+l(l+1)k}{k(k+1)-l(l+1)}$$
$$ \to 2$$

(Note I have used $a_{k+2}$ because if we split the series into the even terms and the odd terms, then we have two series $\Sigma e_nX^k$ and $\Sigma \omega_nX^n$ (e for even and $\omega$... for odd) with $e_{k}=a_{2k}$ and $\omega_k=a_{2k+1}$)

According to the Raabe's rule, $2$ is superior than $1$ so the series converges.

This conclusion is weird because, according to the course I follow, the $l$ constant HAS to be a positive integer, in order to prevent the series from diverging at $X=\pm1$.

Comment: Don’t forget about $X$ in your computation.  The series may diverge for some $X$, and converge for others.

Comment: Yes, it converges for sure for $X\in (-1,1)$ but I think the problem is for $X=\pm1$

Comment: For more information about my problem, here is a SE post that asks for help in the exact same subject as mine : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3880311/convergence-of-a-serie-to-obtain-the-eigenvalues-of-general-legendre-operator (answering it would help me a lot as well!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n}}=\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}.\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}$ so if the D Alembert limit exists (say=c) then c.c=$c^{2}=-1$, which is absurd! Therefore we may conclude that the ratio limit doesn't exist! It is puzzling!! Besides for all large k we have $\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n}}$>0. So how can we have a negative limit?? Your limit is +1 and not -1. Which gives no information about convergence! Tell us more about this l constant!

Comment: Ouh yes sorry, .. thanks for noticing that!

Comment: Nothing peculiar about this $l$ constant, except that if it is chosen as a positive integer, then the serie truncates and becomes a polynomial...